# Handling circular soft deletes for two models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models (Owner and Car), with an one to one relationship between them.  Both models use soft deletes. If either model is soft deleted, it should soft delete it's relation.

Currently, when Owner is deleted, I use events to delete Car:

**App/Models/Owner**

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::deleted(function ($owner) {
        $owner->car->delete();
    });

    static::restored(function ($owner) {
        $owner->car()->withTrashed()->first()->restore();
    });
}
```

This works fine, but I can't work out how to do the same from Car without running into circular logic.  I have tried adding a logical test for `$car->owner` or `$car->owner()->trashed()` but in both cases the page just hangs - presumably as the methods are going in a circle.

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it would be easier all round to use an Observer on each model that watches for its deletion - when deleting, check if the related model is already deleted and if not, delete it (the if not bit would prevent the circularity issue that you appear to be encountering).